# Pseudo-polynomial time algorithm for modified coin change

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, coin-change

I thought of the following problem while thinking of coin change, but I don't know an efficient (pseudo-polynomial time) algorithm to solve it. I'd like to know if there is any pseudo-polynomial time solution or maybe some classic literature on it that I'm missing.

There is a well-known [pseudo-polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time) [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) solution to the coin change problem, which asks the following:

You have [image: n] coins, the [image: ith] of which has a value of [image: vi]. How many subsets of coins exist, such that the sum of the coin values is [image: W]?

The dynamic programming solution runs in [image: O(nW)], and is a classic. But I'm interested in the following slight generalization:

What if the [image: ith] coin no longer has just a value of [image: vi], but instead can assume a set of [image: l_i] values [image: vi = {vi1, vi2, vi3, ..., vili}]? Now, the question is: How many subsets of coins exist, such there exists an assignment of coins to values such that the sum of the values of these coins is [image: W]?

(The classic coin change problem is actually an instance of this problem with [image: li = 1] for all [image: i], so I do not expect a polynomial time solution.)

For example, given [image: n = 3] and [image: W = 10], and the following coins:

1. [image: l1 = 4, v1 = {3, 6, 7, 10}]
2. [image: l2 = 2, v2 = {1, 10}]
3. [image: l3 = 2, v3 = {3, 4}]

Then, there are [image: 4] subsets:

1. Take coin [image: 1] only, assign this coin to have value [image: 10].
2. Take coin [image: 2] only, assign this coin to have value [image: 10].
3. Take coins [image: 1] and [image: 3], assign them to have values [image: 7] and [image: 3], respectively ***or*** [image: 6] and [image: 4], respectively—these are considered to be the same way.
4. Take coins [image: 1], [image: 2] and [image: 3], and assign them to have values [image: 6], [image: 1] and [image: 3], respectively.

The issue I'm having is precisely the third case; it would be easy to modify the classic dynamic programming solution for this problem, but it will count these two subsets as separate because different values are assigned, even though the coins taken are the same.

So far, I have only been able to find the straightforward exponential time algorithm for this problem: consider each of the [image: 2^n] subsets, and run the standard dynamic programming coin change algorithm (which is [image: O(nW^2)]) to check whether this subset of coins is valid, giving an [image: O(2^n*n*W^2)] time algorithm. That's not what I'm looking for here; I'm trying to find a solution without the [image: 2^n] factor.

Can you provide me with a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm to solve this question, or can it be proven that none exists unless, say, P = NP? That is, this problem is NP-complete (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is hard, but the way you asked the question it doesn't seem so.

> Take coins 1 and 3, assign them to have values 7 and 3, respectively or 6 and 4, respectively—these are considered to be the same way.

Let us encode the two equivalent solutions in this way:

1. ((1, 3), (7, 3))
2. ((1, 3), (6, 4))

Now, when we memoize a solution, can't we just ask if the first element of the pair, (1, 3), has already been solved? Then we would suppress computing the (6, 4) solution.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if I understand—are you suggesting memoizing the subsets themselves? Pardon me if I misunderstood your solution, but there are up to 2^n-1 nonempty subsets in a set of n elements, so this will run in Ω(2^n), which is not pseudo-polynomial.

Comment: I would initially probe for (1, 3) already being solved, and in that case would suppress proposing any further (1, 3) solutions. You complained the classic solution "will count these two subsets as separate" and I'm suggesting a "first solution wins" approach that would store only the first of the equivalent solutions.

Comment: I understand this much; the question is how long this would take. How would we "probe" if (1, 3) is already solved? If we would store all possible subsets and probe if they have been solved, then we would need at least Ω(2^n) time and memory (because we need to store all subsets, and each subset still needs to be computed once). I'm looking for something pseudo-polynomial in time and space, so I can't afford the 2^n factor.